# How can I access configuration of Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I try to get the `baseUrl` configuration of Require.js inside a module, but I can't find where it is stored.

```
define([], function() {
  // Here I'd like to access the `baseUrl` require.js is using
  var baseUrl = requirejs.config().baseUrl;
});
```

In my case, the `baseUrl` is set up by Require.js using the `data-main` attribute of the script file.

I know I can request `module` to access the `config` attributes (e.g. `define(['module'])`), but I can't find how to access the higher level of configuration option.

Comment: You trying to just read the URL?

Comment: Well, the value Require.js use as `baseUrl` (from where it load script)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you want to use [toUrl](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload)?

```
define({
    load: function (name, parentRequire, load, config) {
           var fullUrl = parentRequire.toUrl("foo/bar.css");
    }
});
```

**edit:**
Starting in require.js 2.1.3, [calling `toURL` return the path without extension](http://jrburke.com/2013/01/22/requirejs-2.1.3-released/). As so, to get the baseUrl:

```
var baseURL = require.toUrl();
```

Comment: Hi, that's almost what I need. Only, `toURL` always return a ressources file (`.js`) and I'd need the folder.

Comment: Using require 2.3.5, calling `require.toUrl()` without a parameter triggers an error. `toUrl` expects one parameter and it expects it to be a string.

Comment: @JohnSlegers You can just provide an empty string: `require.toUrl('')`.

Answer (score 99):

You can also reach the config into:

```
requirejs.s.contexts._.config
```

to inspect the config object directly.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/Hf-qNmM0ceI

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for weeks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After googling a lot at last i got this perfect solution.

Answer (score 22):

In RequireJS 2.1.5, you can get the base URL just like epascarello says, except you'll need to pass the empty string.

```
var baseURL = require.toUrl('');
```

Comment: FYI: If you use this and you configured urlArgs you will get base url with this attribute.