# RequireJS - check if path is defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have an angular.js application where I am lazy loading controllers and services in the `resolve` block of my state definitions (ui-router). Here is what I do:

```
resolve: {
    loadDependencies: function ($q, $stateParams, cache, session) {
        var module = $stateParams.module;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var controller = 'modules.' + module + '.' + module + 'Controller';
            var service = 'modules.' + module + '.' + module + 'Service';

            // Load the controller and service for the module
            require([controller, service], function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

Before I do `require(...)`, I wish to check if the controller and service paths actually are defined in requireJS.config. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21579941/1470607

Comment: Yep, that works :) I'd mark it as the correct answer if you'd post it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579941/1470607) you can access the whole configuration object via

```
requirejs.s.contexts._.config
```