# Request specific RequireJS configuration context

Tags: javascript, requirejs

If I configure a specific [context](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion):

```
var myRequire = require.config({
  context: 'foo',
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'jquery-1.11.2'
  }
});
```

I can then immediately use `myRequire` to load a module:

```
myRequire(['require', 'jquery'], function (require, $) { /* ... */ });
```

But if I move the configuration to a separate file, how do I retrieve the proper context?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579941/161457) I found that `requirejs.s.contexts['foo'].require` returns the same function as `myRequire`. That seems hacky. Another option would be to define a module for the config and return `myRequire` from it. What is the approved method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

**require.config.js:**

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var myRequire = require.config({
        context: 'foo',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'jquery-1.11.2'
        }
    });

    return {
        myRequire: myRequire
    };
});
```

**main.js:**

```
// does need path and .js extension
requirejs(['/scripts/require.config.js'], function (requireConfig) {
    var myRequire = requireConfig.myRequire;

    myRequire(['require', 'jquery'], function (require, $) { /* ... */ });
});
```

I'm still open to better ways, and I have not tested this with r.js.

Comment: This is pretty much what came to my mind when I saw your question last night but I was busy then.